# Generate a new canvas for every new keypress (shooting gun turret)

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, kivy, kivy-language

First, I am a beginner with kivy, and not very experienced in Python either.
The following program is strictly meant to educate myself in kivy basics, nothing more.

The program is a game where the user controls a gun turret. He shots at objects that bounce around in the program window, while points and time used are shown in the bar below. (Currently occupied by a button.) The keys that turn the turret are "A" and "D", while "P" is for shooting.

The problem I am currently having is this:
I need to generate additional projectile graphics every time the user press "P". At a later stage I will also need to generate and remove target objects graphics when they get hit by a shot, which I guess will involve the same technique.

How should I go about to generate additional canvas´ and\or ellipse objects? (the graphical representation of each shot)

My Python code:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '900')
Config.set('graphics','resizable',0)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.properties import ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import math

from kivy.core.window import Window

class MainScreen(BoxLayout): #Contains the whole program

    #Turret rotation:
    the_angle = NumericProperty(0)

    #Projectile vector:
    the_pos_x = NumericProperty(0)
    the_pos_y = NumericProperty(0)
    the_pos = ReferenceListProperty(the_pos_x, the_pos_y)

    #Shots data:
    shot_fired = BooleanProperty(False)

    shot_count = NumericProperty(0)
    angle_list = ListProperty([])
    pos_list_x = ListProperty([])
    pos_list_y = ListProperty([])


    def update(self, dt):
        if self.shot_fired == True:
            self.shot_count += 1
            self.angle_list.append(self.the_angle)
            self.pos_list_x.append(400)
            self.pos_list_y.append(400)
            self.shot_fired = False

        for i in range(0, self.shot_count):
            self.shoot(i, self.angle_list[i], self.pos_list_x[i], self.pos_list_y[i])




    def shoot(self, cur_shot, the_angle, pos_x, pos_y):

        #Make correct shot data:
        velocity = 1.5
        angle_rad = math.radians(the_angle+90)
        pos_x += ( math.cos(angle_rad)*velocity )
        pos_y += ( math.sin(angle_rad)*velocity )

        #Give the shots positions new data :
        self.the_pos_x = pos_x
        self.the_pos_y = pos_y

        #Update data for the next round of this function:
        self.pos_list_x[cur_shot] = pos_x
        self.pos_list_y[cur_shot] = pos_y


    def keypress(self, *args):
        the_key = args[3]
        if the_key == "a":
            self.the_angle += 1.5
        elif the_key == "d":
            self.the_angle += -1.5
        elif the_key == "p":
            self.shot_fired = True




class GameScreen(RelativeLayout): #The game part of the screen
    pass

class Gun(Widget): #Holds canvas and drawings for gun
    pass    

class Projectile(Widget): #Holds canvas and drawings for projectile
    pass    

class InfoBar(FloatLayout): #Holds point counters and buttons
    pass


#Set screen size and prevent resizing:
Window.size = (800, 900)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("interface.kv")
        game = MainScreen()
        Window.bind(on_key_down=game.keypress)
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
        return game


MyApp().run()
```

My kv code:

```
<MainScreen>:

    the_angle: 45
    the_pos: [400,400]

    GameScreen:
        size_hint:(None,None)
        size:800,800
        pos_hint:{"top":1, "left":1}

        Gun:
            canvas.before:
                PushMatrix
                Rotate:
                    axis: 0,0,1
                    angle: root.the_angle
                    origin: 400,400


            canvas:
                Rectangle:
                    size:50,100
                    pos: 400,400

            canvas.after:
                PopMatrix


        Projectile:

            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    size:10,20
                    pos: root.the_pos[0], root.the_pos[1]


    InfoBar:
        size_hint:(None,None)
        size:800,100
        pos_hint:{"bottom":1, "left":1}
        Button:
```

Comment: edit your code please

Comment: What should be edited?

Comment: indents. It's not easy to to copy and paste your code to test it

Comment: See if it works better now :)